# MQTT, ESP8266 acting a random manner

Tags: javascript, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I have been developing a home automation system
Scenario:

ESP8266 sending keep alive to Rasp pi MQTT server

webpage on Chrome using IBM utility javascript Paho client

ESP sends alive every 10 secs and shows when it receives its own message including received time, this proves the server is sending the messages back on time.

Webpage(also has timer) displays the time messages are received with the message

Messages are received on the webpage in a random manner, by this I mean that no messages arrive for a long time then a glut arrives all at the same time
from the esp I can see that the messages are being received when the are published. there seems to be a problem in the webpage code
I am just wondering if anyone has seen this before and can point me in the right direction, my code is below:

thanks in advance
Dave

```js
/*
Original Copyright (c) 2015 IBM Corp.
Eclipse Paho MQTT-JS Utility
This utility can be used to test MQTT brokers
its been bent by me to fit my needs
*/

// global variables
 var MyLib = {};   // space for my bits
 MyLib.theMessage = "";   // received message
 MyLib.theTopic  = "";   // received topic
 MyLib.clientId  = 'webRunpage2' + (Math.random() * 10);
 MyLib.connected  = false;
 MyLib.ticker  = setInterval(function(){MyLib.tickTime ++;}, 1000); // 5secs 
 MyLib.tickTime  = 0;
 MyLib.aliveTimer = setInterval(function(){keepMeAlive()}, 90000); // 1.5 mins
//=============================================================
function keepMeAlive() {
 var topic='webpage', message='KeepAlive';
 publish(topic, 1, message, false); // keeps the conection open
 console.info("Alive Time: ", MyLib.tickTime);
}
//=============================================================
function onMessageArrived(message) {
 MyLib.theTopic = message.destinationName;  MyLib.theMessage = message.payloadString;
 var topic = MyLib.theTopic;  
 var messg = MyLib.theMessage;
 var id = messg.substring(0,6); 
 console.log('Message Recieved: Topic: ', message.destinationName, "Time ", MyLib.tickTime);
}
//=============================================================
function onFail(context) {
  console.log("Failed to connect");
  MyLib.connected = false;
}
//=============================================================
function connectionToggle(){
  if(MyLib.connected){ disconnect();
  } else { connect(); }
}
//=============================================================
function onConnect(context) {
  // Once a connection has been made
 console.log("Client Connected");
 document.getElementById("status").value = "Connected";
 MyLib.connected = true;
 client.subscribe('LIGHTS/#');  // subscribe to all 'LIGHTS' members
}
//=================================================
 // called when the client loses its connection
 function onConnectionLost() {
  console.log("Connection Lost: ");
  document.getElementById("status").value = "Connection Lost";
  MyLib.connected = false;
  connectionToggle();
 }
//=============================================================
function connect(){
    var hostname = "192.168.1.19";
    var port = 1884;
    var clientId = MyLib.clientId;
    var path = "/ws";
    var user = "dave";
    var pass = "vineyard01";
    var keepAlive = 120;   // 2 mins stay alive
    var timeout = 3;
    var ssl = false;
    var cleanSession = true;  //*******************
    var lastWillTopic = "lastwill";
    var lastWillQos = 0;
    var lastWillRetain = false;
    var lastWillMessage = "its Broken";

    if(path.length > 0){
      client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname, Number(port), path, clientId);
    } else {
      client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(hostname, Number(port), clientId);
    }
   // console.info('Connecting to Server: Hostname: ', hostname, '. Port: ', port, '. Path: ', client.path, '. Client ID: ', clientId);
    // set callback handlers
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
    var options = {
      invocationContext: {host : hostname, port: port, path: client.path, clientId: clientId},
      timeout: timeout,
      keepAliveInterval:keepAlive,
      cleanSession: cleanSession,
      useSSL: ssl,
      onSuccess: onConnect,
      onFailure: onFail
    };
    if(user.length > 0){ options.userName = user; }
    if(pass.length > 0){ options.password = pass; }

    if(lastWillTopic.length > 0){
      var lastWillMessage = new Paho.MQTT.Message(lastWillMessage);
      lastWillMessage.destinationName = lastWillTopic;
      lastWillMessage.qos = lastWillQos;
      lastWillMessage.retained = lastWillRetain;
      options.willMessage = lastWillMessage;
    }

    // connect the client
    client.connect(options);
}
//=============================================================
function disconnect(){
   // console.info('Disconnecting from Server');
    client.disconnect();
    MyLib.connected = false;
}
//=============================================================
function publish(topic, qos, message, retain){
// console.info('Publishing Message: Topic: ', topic, '. QoS: ' + qos + '. Message: ', message, '. Retain: ', retain);
    message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(message);
    message.destinationName = topic;
    message.qos = Number(qos);
    message.retained = retain;
    client.send(message);
}
//=============================================================
function subscribe(topic){
    var qos = 1;
    client.subscribe(topic, {qos: Number(qos)});
}
//=============================================================
// left next 4 functions but not used
function unsubscribe(topic){
    client.unsubscribe(topic, {
         onSuccess: unsubscribeSuccess,
         onFailure: unsubscribeFailure,
         invocationContext: {topic : topic}
     });
}
//=============================================================
function unsubscribeSuccess(context){
 //   console.info('Successfully unsubscribed from ', context.invocationContext.topic);
}
//=============================================================
function unsubscribeFailure(context){
//    console.info('Failed to  unsubscribe from ', context.invocationContext.topic);
}

//=============================================================
// Just in case someone sends html
function safe_tags_regex(str) {
   return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
//=============================================================
```

Comment: after banging my head against this for another 24 hours it appears that the problem is caused by the 1 second tick. If I replace MyLib.ticktime ++ with a function and in that increment tickTime then publishes to MQTT messages arrive as expected.